# I rebooted my computed and now gnome3 runs like gnome classic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome3

I may have not described the problem correctly in the title. It's probably a simple issue, but I'm not sure how to go about diagnosing it.

I was running gnome 3 for awhile using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

This morning I installed the critical updates from Ubuntu's software manager and that worked like normal.

However, later in the day the computer crashed to the login screen for some reason. I don't know why. I think I was attempting to open chrome or something.

Now, whenever I log in I get the gnome classic look and feel. I'm not even sure if Gnome3 is running.

I don't know where to look for error messages or how to diagnose and fix what went wrong. I'd like to get back to Gnome3 because I feel lost without its super key.

---

As I learn things I'll post them here.

---

@Keltari asked if video drivers were installed.

I found the apt-get logfile in /var/log/apt and this is what was installed this morning:

Start-Date: 2013-08-26  10:42:27
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.165'

Install: 
linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic:amd64 (3.2.0-52.78), 
linux-headers-3.2.0-52:amd64 (3.2.0-52.78), 
linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic:amd64 (3.2.0-52.78)

Upgrade: 
rpm2cpio:amd64 (4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1, 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2), 
fglrx-amdcccle-updates:amd64 (9.000-0ubuntu0.3, 12.104-0ubuntu0.0.1), 
lsb-qt4:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), 
lsb-desktop:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), 
linux-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.51.61, 3.2.0.52.62), 
librpmio2:amd64 (4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1, 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2), 
librpm2:amd64 (4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1, 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2), 
rpm-common:amd64 (4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1, 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2), 
boot-sav-extra:amd64 (3.199~ppa12~precise, 3.199~ppa16~precise), 
fglrx-updates:amd64 (9.000-0ubuntu0.3, 12.104-0ubuntu0.0.1), 
linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.51.61, 3.2.0.52.62), 
linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.2.0.51.61, 3.2.0.52.62), 
boot-repair:amd64 (3.199~ppa12~precise, 3.199~ppa16~precise), 
lsb-base:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), 
rpm:amd64 (4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1, 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2), 
librpmbuild2:amd64 (4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1, 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2), 
boot-sav:amd64 (3.199~ppa12~precise, 3.199~ppa16~precise), 
lsb-invalid-mta:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), 
jockey-common:amd64 (0.9.7-0ubuntu7.9, 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.10), 
whoopsie:amd64 (0.1.32, 0.1.33), 
jockey-gtk:amd64 (0.9.7-0ubuntu7.9, 0.9.7-0ubuntu7.10), 
librpmsign0:amd64 (4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.1, 4.9.1.1-1ubuntu0.2), 
linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.2.0-51.77, 3.2.0-52.78), 
lsb-graphics:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), 
lsb-core:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3), 
lsb-release:amd64 (4.0-0ubuntu20.2, 4.0-0ubuntu20.3)

End-Date: 2013-08-26  10:44:30

A more readable list is: linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic, linux-headers-3.2.0-52, linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic, boot-repair, boot-sav, boot-sav-extra, fglrx-amdcccle-updates, fglrx-updates, jockey-common, jockey-gtk, librpm2, librpmbuild2, librpmio2, librpmsign0, linux-generic, linux-headers-generic, linux-image-generic, linux-libc-dev, lsb-base, lsb-core, lsb-desktop, lsb-graphics, lsb-invalid-mta, lsb-qt4, lsb-release, rpm, rpm-common, rpm2cpio, whoopsie,

Comment: did the video drivers get updated?

Comment: @Keltari : I updated my post with what was updated. I have nvidia graphics, and I don't see those drivers there. is lsb-graphics anything?

Comment: fglrx-amdcccle-updates, fglrx-updates - remove those and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing fglrx-amdcccle-updates, fglrx-updates.  I have a HP laptop and when those got updated it broke Cinnamon on Mint.

Comment: this did the trick

Comment: I have the exact same symptoms, but do not have these packages installed. Have you got any idea how to debug what's going wrong in my case? I can ask a new question and post the packages that were upgraded if that helps.

Comment: @MikeH-R Unfortunately, I dont know that much about Linux.  You shoudl ask a new question.